# Hebrew Letters and corresponding body parts

Tags: hebrew, mysticism-kabbalah, aleph-bet-letters, parts-of-the-body

When I was a little child, I remember being taught that each of the Hebrew letters had a corresponding body part. I am sure I learned what they were at the time, but I've long forgotten most of them.

When I try to look for information on this, I can find a lot of people mentioning the concept, but not an actual list of which letters were for each body part.

Can anyone guide me?

Comment: There is an Artscroll book that may have what you're looking for (although it's been a while since I read it, so I'm not certain): https://www.artscroll.com/Books/9781422610367.html

Comment: Certain letters may have been named after body parts, directly. Yod = hand; kaf = palm; ayin = eye; peh = mouth; resh = head; shin = tooth.

Comment: @Salmononius2 I own the book and I don't remember it touching this at all.

Comment: @Dr.Shmuel is right, it was as a memory aid for when I was a child. I would be interested to have seen the deleted comment!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may be looking for a concept discussed in *Sefer Yetzirah*.  I don't have a proper copy nearby, so this excerpt (presumably the first section) from a *Tikun Leil Shavuos* may be helpful:

> קשר עשרים ושתים אותיות התורה בלשונו וכו'.‏
>   אויר רויה גויה, ארץ קר וחום ובטן, ושמים ראש, זהו אמ"ש:‏
>   שבתאי, שבת, ופה. צדק, אחד בשבת, ועין ימין. מאדים, שני בשבת, ועין שמאל.
>   חמה, שלישי בשבת, ואף ימין. נגה, רביעי בשבת, ואף שמאל. כוכב, חמישי בשבת, ואזן ימין.
>   לבנה ,ששי בשבת ואזן שמאל. זה בג"ד כפר"ת:‏
>   ואלה שנים עשר מזלות: טלה, ניסן, כבד. שור, אייר, מרה. תאומים, סיון, טחול. סרטן, תמוז, 
>   המסס. אריה, אב, כוליא ימין. בתולה, אלול, כוליא שמאל. מאזנים, תשרי, קרקבן. עקרב, 
>   מרחשון, קבה. קשת, כסלו, יד ימין. גדי, טבת, יד שמאל. דלי, שבט, רגל ימין. דגים, אדר, 
>   רגל שמאל. זהו ה"ו, ז"ח, ט"י, ל"ן, ס"ע, צ"ק.‏

This works out to be something to the effect of (translation mine, on the fly): *Aleph* - the גויה; *bet* - mouth; *gimel* - right eye; *daled* - left eye;
*hei* - liver; *vav* - the מרה (humor); *zayin* - the טחול; *ches* - the מסס;
*tes* - right kidney; *yod* - left kidney; *kof* - right nostril; *lamed* - the קרקבן;
*mem* - abdomen; *nun* - the קבה; *samech* - right hand; *ayin* - left hand;
*pei* - left nostril; *tzadi* - right foot; *kuf* - left foot; *reish* - right ear;
*shin* - head; *tav* - left ear.

The *B'nei Yissoschor* quotes the *Sefer Yetzira* in the first chapter for each month, and explains the connection between the month, zodiac sign, organ, and letter.

It is possible (likely?) that the list you learned as a child is entirely different, but I believe this list is somewhat authoritative.

Comment: I don’t think even the gaon learned Sefer yetizrah as a kid; could be wrong though

Comment: @Dr.Shmuel The Vilna Gaon?  I suspect he at least recited _Tikun_.  However, this is a possible list, that could have been taught separately. It's a list, at least.

Comment: Sorry, I missed that part. You’re right. (Also, it’s not a stretch, Vilna Gaon did a lot in his childhood)

Comment: Ahhh, yes, this is exactly it! My mother taught me a little dance that I could do when I recited it and this certainly corresponds to what I remember of that. Thank you!

Comment: I stand corrected- he did just that! See R. Chaim Volozhon intro to sifra detzniyusa.

Answer (score 0):

According to Sefer Yetzira. The face includes :
The ב is the right eye representing חכמה  חסד , also Sunday and the moon.
ג is the right ear, גבורה, Monday, and Mars.
ד is the right nostril, Tuesday, תפארת, and the sun.
כ is left eye, Venus, נצח, Wednesday .
פ is left ear, הוד, Thursday, and Mercury.
ר is left nostril, יסוד, Friday, and Saturn.
ת represents the mouth while  circling the whole of the face corresponding to action, שבת, Jupiter, and מלכות.

Comment: Where does the Sefer Yetzirah say this?

Comment: Sefer Yetzira written by Aryeh Kaplan I believe it’s chapter 4

Comment: Based on the _Sefer Yetzira_ on [Sefaria.org](https://www.sefaria.org/Sefer_Yetzirah.4?lang=bi), the order of the planets from ב to ת is שצ''מ חנכ''ל, whereas you listed them the opposite direction.  Either way, I suppose I ought to correct my response.

Comment: It’s all about where you are looking from!!!! Keep in mind zeir anpin is behind you......